# What should be in a .gitignore file for a Kony project?

Tags: git, temenos-quantum

For my current project I am working on a Kony project.  (Before anyone asks Kony is a requirement)  There are a lot of files in the project some appear to be changing after doing nothing more than opening the project.  So that leaves me wondering what files or directories are safe to ignore?

Comment: check this link 'https://github.com/github/gitignore'

Comment: No luck with that one.

Comment: @ProgrammingPope please consider having a look at my answer and marking it as the correct one.

Comment: About the comment by @AnjaneyuluBattula I've recently created a [pull request](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/2914) to get the `.gitignore` template for Kony Visualizer projects added to the drop-down  when creating a new repo at Github.com. You can find it [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/2914)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .gitignore for my current project. I believe that `defaults/` can also be ignored.

```
# Kony Studio
jssrc/
*.properties
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post but I've often encountered people asking the same question. Moreover the answer to this question evolves over time because the Visualizer implementation changes a lot from version to version and so it's difficult to keep up. For example `sdkplugin.properties` is an auto-generated file that in Visualizer versions prior to 7.3 used to be in the project root and could not be added to `.gitignore` because Visualizer was not able to re-create it when missing. But I've found that starting with Visualizer version 7.3 this file has been moved to `resources/customlibs/sdkplugin.properties` and now Visaulizer *can* in fact re-create it if missing -i.e. you can now add it to your `.gitignore`.

I've been working on this for a while and I've decided to gather my notes in a pseudo-project I've called [vis-git: ***"Best Practices on using Kony Visualizer with Git"***](https://github.com/mig82/vis-git) , which I'll try to keep up to date with my findings in the newer versions of Visualizer. I hope it's useful to others.

However, if you're in a hurry and are just looking for the quick answer, here it is:

***.gitignore***

```
/jssrc/*
!/resources/customlibs/jsSrc

# Starting with Visualizer 8.0 the Ant Contrib Jar used for the build process will
# be regenerated when the build is fired. If you're using Visualizer 7.x then comment out
# this line. Vis 7.x will not regenerate this jar and ignoring it will break your project.
ant-contrib-0.6.jar

# Binaries.
/binaries
*.apk
*.KAR

# Starting with Vis 7.3 the /sdkplugin.properties file has been moved to
# /resources/customlibs/sdkplugin.properties and can be automatically re-created by Vis
# during the build.
resources/customlibs/sdkplugin.properties

# The jar's and zip's under these directories can be ignored so long as
# sdkplugin.properties (See above) is also ignored. The missing sdkplugin.properties will
# trigger the regeneration of these jar's and zip's during the build.
resources/customlibs/lib/android/
resources/customlibs/lib/tabrcandroid/
resources/customlibs/lib/iphone/
resources/customlibs/lib/ipad/
resources/customlibs/lib/windows10/
resources/customlibs/lib/winphone10/

# Other Visualizer auto-generated files.
/.webmeta
middleware.properties
splashscreenproperties.json

# Visualizer headless build configuration files
HeadlessBuild.properties
HeadlessBuild-Global.properties

# Visualizer modules which are automatically re-created when missing
modules/mbaasconfig.js

# Auxiliary files generated during a build to expose the widget ID's for testing.
resources/mobile/native/android/values/widgetids.xml
resources/tablet/native/androidtab/values/widgetids.xml

# NPM dependencies folder which gets created for apps using the "Nitro" Cordova integration
# when you choose NOT to use a globally installed Cordova SDK by unchecking
# `Project Settings>Application>Cordova Settings>Use globally installed Cordova version`.
node_modules

# When using the "Nitro" Cordova integration, the Cordova `plugins` and `platforms`
# directories can be ignored as with any Cordova project.
cordovatemp
web/cordova/plugins
web/cordova/platforms

# Auto-generated temporary internationalization files.
resources/i18n/

# Logs created by building from the command line.
velocity.log

# A Logger FFI that gets bundled with each project and is auto-generated by Visualizer with each build.
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/android/com/konylabs/ffi/N_KonyLogger.java
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/tabrcandroid/com/konylabs/ffi/N_KonyLogger.java
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/kiosk/KonyLogger.js
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/kiosk/KonyLogger.xml
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/windows8/KonyLogger.js
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/windows8/KonyLogger.xml
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winmobile/KonyLogger.js
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winmobile/KonyLogger.xml
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winphone8/KonyLogger.js
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winphone8/KonyLogger.xml
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winphone81s/KonyLogger.js
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winphone81s/KonyLogger.xml
resources/customlibs/jsXml/KonyLogger.js
resources/customlibs/jsXml/KonyLogger.xml

# A Single Sign-On FFI that gets bundled with each project and is auto-generated by Visualizer with each build.
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/kiosk/SSOFFI.js
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/kiosk/SSOFFI.xml
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/windows8/SSOFFI.js
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/windows8/SSOFFI.xml
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winmobile/SSOFFI.js
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winmobile/SSOFFI.xml
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winphone8/SSOFFI.js
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winphone8/SSOFFI.xml
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winphone81s/SSOFFI.js
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/winphone81s/SSOFFI.xml
resources/customlibs/jsXml/SSOFFI.js
resources/customlibs/jsXml/SSOFFI.xml

# A utility FFI that gets bundled with each project and is auto-generated by Visualizer with each build.
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/android/com/konylabs/ffi/ND_binary_util.java
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/android/com/konylabs/ffi/N_binarydata.java
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/tabrcandroid/com/konylabs/ffi/ND_binary_util.java
resources/customlibs/jsSrc/tabrcandroid/com/konylabs/ffi/N_binarydata.java
resources/customlibs/jsXml/binary.util.js
resources/customlibs/jsXml/binary.util.xml
resources/customlibs/jsXml/binarydata.js
resources/customlibs/jsXml/binarydata.xml
```

**EDIT:**

I've recently published an article to Kony Basecamp ["Git for Visualizer Projects"](https://basecamp.kony.com/s/article-detail/a046A00000AT2AlQAL/git-for-visualizer-projects) where I dive much deeper into this subject. It includes a `.gitignore`, a `.gitattributes` and much more. You can find it [here](https://basecamp.kony.com/s/article-detail/a046A00000AT2AlQAL/git-for-visualizer-projects).